# Does idiomatic rust code always avoid 'unsafe'?

Tags: rust

I'm doing leetcode questions to get better at solving problems and expressing those solutions in rust, and I've come across a case where it feels like the most natural way of expressing my answer includes unsafe code. Here's what I wrote:

```rust
const _0: u8 = '0' as u8;
const _1: u8 = '1' as u8;

pub fn add_binary(a: String, b: String) -> String {
    let a = a.as_bytes();
    let b = b.as_bytes();
    let len = a.len().max(b.len());
    let mut result = vec![_0; len];
    let mut carry = 0;
    for i in 1..=len {
        if i <= a.len() && a[a.len() - i] == _1 {
            carry += 1
        }
        if i <= b.len() && b[b.len() - i] == _1 {
            carry += 1
        }
        if carry & 1 == 1 {
            result[len - i] = _1;
        }
        carry >>= 1;
    }
    if carry == 1 {
        result.insert(0, _1);
    }
    unsafe { String::from_utf8_unchecked(result) }
}
```

The only usage of unsafe is to do an unchecked conversion of a `Vec<u8>` to a `String`, and there is no possibility of causing undefined behaviour in this case because the Vec always just contains some sequence of two different valid ascii characters. I know I could easily do a checked cast and unwrap it, but that feels a bit silly because of how certain I am that the check can never fail. In idiomatic rust, is this bad practice? Should unsafe be unconditionally avoided unless the needed performance can't be achieved without it, or are there exceptions (possibly like this) where it's okay? At risk of making the question too opinionated, what are the rules that determine when it is and isn't okay to use unsafe?

Comment: The documentation for `from_utf8` says the same thing as your own post (emphasis mine): "**If you are sure that the byte slice is valid UTF-8**, and you don't want to incur the overhead of the validity check, there is an unsafe version of this function, from_utf8_unchecked, which has the same behavior but skips the check." - so while `unsafe` should be avoided, as this case is easily _provably_ "safe" (because every 7-bit ASCII character is also valid UTF-8) you're fine.

Comment: I'm not a Rust expert, but I wonder if there's a `from_ascii7` which accepts `[u7]` ([which is a thing](https://docs.rs/ux/0.0.1/ux/struct.u7.html), apparently) which would then be safe and not need a UTF-8 safety check, hmmm. You could build one yourself, I suppose.

Comment: @Dai I know that I'm using the function correctly, and that this is exactly what it was intended for. My question is specifically about whether it's good practice - a language having support for something doesn't mean you should ever use it. The entire value of rust is the stability that comes from all the checks, so I'm not sure if it's just always frowned upon to use unsafe, even in cases where it still works.

Comment: It kind of hurts my brain to imagine the implications of a u7 data type, especially in this context. I would assume that it still takes the full 8 bits, because otherwise addressing will get difficult real difficult real fast. That means that it's really just doing a simplified version of the check earlier, and I would be willing to bet that the cast from &[u7] to &[u8] looks even more unsafe if you want to do it without overhead.

Comment: It's somewhat of a controversial question, but I'd say that idiomatic Rust code avoids unsafe except where it provably helps with performance or is necessary for other reasons (such as interfacing with C code). The tricky thing about unsafe is that its safety depends not only on the stuff inside the block, but also on the stuff outside of it. Although a use of unsafe may appear safe *now*, it's not easy to be sure that it will still be safe after someone refactors the adjacent code. Safe Rust doesn't have that issue, which is why you should avoid unsafe unless it brings something to the table.

Comment: I would say the answer is unequivocally **No**. Idiomatic Rust code will always use `unsafe` where it is necessary. `unsafe` is necessary here to avoid the redundant UTF-8 check. Angelicos's answer argues that you *should not want* to avoid the redundant check, and they may be correct, but nevertheless if you *do* want to avoid the check, `unsafe` is the idiomatic way to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid unsafe unless there are 2 situations:

1. You are doing something which impossible to do in safe code e.g. FFI-calls. It is a main reason why unsafe ever exists.
2. You proved using benchmarks that unsafe provide big speed-up and this code is bottleneck.

Your arguing

> I know I could easily do a checked cast and unwrap it, but that feels a bit silly because of how certain I am that the check can never fail.

is valid about **current** version of your code but you would need to keep this unsafe in mind during all further development.

Unsafe greatly increase cognitive complexity of code. You cannot change any place in your function without keeping unsafe in mind, for example.

I doubt that utf8 validation adds more overhead than possible reallocation in `result.insert(0, _1);` in your code.

Other nitpicks:

1. You should add a comment in unsafe section which explains why it is safe. It would make easier to read a code for a other people (or other you after a year of don't touching it).
2. You could define your constants as `const _0: u8 = b'0';`

Comment: "You could define your constants as const _0: u8 = b'0';" at which point the constants seem entirely unnecessary: I expect they were really shortcuts for "convert char to byte" but `_0` is not really any gain over `b'0'`.